# How can I send data to an iBeacon ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

If I use beacon in a store,the device can push some advertisement to customer`s phone.
How can I push the advertisement to the beacon device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** send message to other via beacon device. Do you have beacon device in store? If Yes, your app must installed in user device which is also in foreground while they entered into your store. So while your beacon device broadcasting, your app can detect accurately where they are. and your app must do some calculation based on location(use triangle theory). Send this information to your server, they will send information to your customer. For example, if your customer now in center of your store, you can popup ads with product image(Flat 50% offer...)

See [this apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html) to learn more about beacon.

Comment: The app doesn't have to be in foreground. It can register for beacon notification of a particular UUID in the background and then use this to post a local notification to the user, prompting them to bring the app to the foreground.

Comment: @Paulw11 Check with your device. Location update only received some minutes after went to background.

Comment: Correct, but this is still a valid (and quite likely) use case for iBeacons - app running in background when user enters store.  Foreground gives a quicker response, but it is not required.

Comment: @Paulw11 But this is limitation, we couldn't break this.

Comment: I was just clarifying that the app doesn't need to be in the foreground (as per your answer)

Comment: NO. app should be in foreground. Because while went to foreground, max of 5 min, you can get callback. After that, connection will break down. When I test with my device, I encountered this problem[iPodTouch-5]

Comment: I created a quick test app, left it in the background overnight and within 15 seconds of plugging in my iBeacon a local notification was posted. Perhaps this may help - http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html

Answer (score 3):

I beacons are not two way communication devices, they are low powered bluetooth devices that advertise some specific info. So it's only one way. There are only two modes of operations for  a beacon , as region-monitoring and ranging.

Here's guide on how these beacons work...
http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/how-ibeacons-work/